# using @ManyToMany relationship without @JoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, persistence

i just want to know the difference between using  **@ManyToMany** relationship **wit @JoinColumn**
and using it **without @JoinColumn**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A many-to-many association always needs a join table. A join column is not sufficient: it only enables a one-to-many association.

If you don't specify any `@JoinTable` annotation on the association, then default values will be used. Hibernate wil use a join table with a default name and default columns composed from the names and IDs of the associated entities.

Comment: ah you are right, the one to many can be used without join column.

Comment: that's it, if you don't use @JoinTable, a default "@JoinTable" will be created.